# Flurry analytics events not showing

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I have flurry setup and in my event logs I see everything coming in but when I click on Event Summary I see nothing. Also I'm unable to setup funnels or anything using custom events.

The code has been live and tracking for 5 days. Is it just taking a really long time or is whats showing up in the event log not ever going to show up in the event summary?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so apparently at some point I clicked on the filter link. I thought this would filter my results to just this event but what it really does is achieve the event and no longer shows it in the events. To fix it I had to go to

Manage > Events and then untick all the events.